# How to create a includes folder inside sites/all/module/custom/<includes>

Tags: 7

I want to create a folder name include in-side sites/all/custom/contrib/  and  inside this want to write some `.inc` files like `date.inc`, `string.inc` in each file a class is created which holds function.

Now I want to use this functions in each module under sites/all/custom/contrib. I have 10 custom module so this .inc functions are available to each custom module.

What is the directory structure I have to follow and how can I achieve this?

Comment: create one custom module with all your functions, and enable it after you enable this module you can use those functions on other custom modules.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your custom modules, just create a directory **includes** and place your .inc files inside it.

To use the .inc files in your .module file, you can use [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7).